# updating configarable option in magento cart page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How can we add configuration option on cart page in magento and update it automatically , including price change, when selected option get change.

I want to know how can we update price and whole cart on selecting configurable options on cart page itself.

Is there any extension or we can do using core coding?

refer cart for configurable product in this site http://www.wehkamp.nl/Winkelmand/Winkelmand.aspx

Comment: I was able to get attribute on the cart page, but not able to functional as the product detail page, means on changing any option, it should also change second dependent attributes value and price accordingly.